# How to setup Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn

How to best use Azure CDN to enhance the reliability of accessing Azure storage?

Hi,

In our current system implementation, we have use an azure storage account to store some essential information of the system. Thus, the storage becomes the single point of failure. In order to enhance the reliability of this mechanism, I am considering to use Azure CDN at the top of storage account.

Since I am new to this product, wondering what is the best practice here. And also here are some questions.

1. I figure out Azure CDN could provide a cache at the top of storage, but what if I updated the blobs, but the content inside cache doesn't expire, how to force cdn to bypass the cache to fetch the up-to-date content. Could I setup the CDN to detect the update in the storage and catch the new stuff?
2. Need to confirm, if I create the content delivery network (CDN) in a resource group locating in East US, the cdn is not only available in this region, which means if Azure East US went down, we could still access the endpoint empowered by another edge node in different region.

Also, there is another approach I could think of, Azure storage Geo-redundant storage(GRS). So in this case, I could simply add a try catch in the code, whenever I got a failure from the original storage endpoint, I route to grs endpoint and do the same get.

Which way do you think is better?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be use the CDN with (RAGRS) storage account. CDN is a global resource which deploys at each of the edges providing far better Caching and Acceleration.

You can purge the CDN cache every time you update the storage blob. Normally this is done using your CI/CD pipeline at deployment.

In Azure DevOps there's already a task, or you can google for various ways to purge the cache.

- Using the azure portal:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint
- Script:
  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Purge-Azure-CDN-endpoint-042fb00d

Comment: Currently the storage is GRS, is this possible to switch to enable RA-GRS for the same storage account?

Comment: Yes you can. Refer: https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-switch-azure-storage-replication-strategy/